# MongoDB stalling at 100 writes/s but benchmark says 54000 writes/s

Tags: amazon-ec2, performance, mongodb

I am running MongoDB (v3.4 Community Edition) on an AWS EC2 m4.large instance. I installed it according to this [MongoDB tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/). I haven't modified any MongoDB config. I haven't configured any replica set or shard. I have a Jersey API which interacts with MongoDB using [org.mongodb.morphia (v1.3.2) Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/getting-started/quick-tour/).

I have created a load test using SoapUI where I make 100 calls to API which in turn create 100 write operations (one document is created in one collection per write operation) for MongoDB. I run the test for 24 hours. At the end, I see my webserver trying to communicate with the Mongo server but the connection is timing out and the host CPU is running at 100%. I conclude that the MongoDB server is choking.

I then tried this [benchmarking exercise](https://vladmihalcea.com/2013/12/01/mongodb-facts-80000-insertssecond-on-commodity-hardware/), still with a database hosted on an m4.large. 50,000,000 records were created in 923.133 seconds i.e. 54,113 insertions per second. That is over 500 times faster!

If MongoDB is performing so well then why it is choking at 100 insertion per second when going through JAVA driver? Is the Java driver slow? Is my use of the Java driver wrong? Is my EC2 instance size is too low? Would it help to add replication (RAID and Replica sets)?

I am new to MongoDB hosting and really appreciate your help learning.

Update:

**Load Test Configuration:**

Client : SoapUI (v5.3), Web server : Tomcat 8, Java : v1.8, MongoDB : v3.4.
I am running all my servers in AWS Mumbai region. I am hosting Web Sever and MongoDB server on same EC2 instance (m4.large) and I am running client on Windows machine (t2.micro).

After further investigation, I think the bottleneck is in my code. I used *Mongostat* utility to see how mongodb is behaving. I found that, at start there are two connection. Connections jumps to 102 as soon as I start my load test (Connections never go above 102 even at 1000 request per second and MongoDB close them after long time). Load is 100 request per second. Here is gif which shows this behaviour.

[image]

I found some questions with similar problem but answers didnt reveal much. I have taken care of the suggestions. Here are some samples,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580147/mongo-connection-leak-with-morphia

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469656/spring-data-mongodb-not-closing-mongodb-connections

**Java Code:**

*Creating Connection:* I am using one connection for my application as recommended by MongoDB. Implementing Singleton pattern.

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

    private static volatile MongoClient instance;
    private static String cloudhost="localhost";

    private DatabaseConnection() { }

    public synchronized static MongoClient getMongoClient() {
        if (instance == null ) {
            synchronized (DatabaseConnection.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress(cloudhost, 27017);
                    List<MongoCredential> credentialsList = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
                    MongoCredential credentia = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                        "test", "test", "test".toCharArray());
                    credentialsList.add(credentia);
                    instance = new MongoClient(addr, credentialsList); 

                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

*Sample Data Access Object class :*

```
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.dao.BasicDAO;

import Sample;

public class SampleDao extends BasicDAO<Sample, String>{

    public SampleDao(Class<Sample> entityClass, Datastore ds) {
        super(entityClass, ds);
    }
}
```

*Sample Repository Class:* This class is responsible for interacting with DB and persist the document

```
public class SampleRepository {

    private SampleDao sampleDao;

    public SampleRepository ()
    {
        try 
        {
            MongoClient mongoClient = DatabaseConnection.getMongoClient();
            Datastore ds = new Morphia().map(Pour.class)
                    .createDatastore(mongoClient, "test");
            sampleDao = new SampleDao(Sample.class,ds);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            logger.error("Error while creating SampleDao", e);
        }
    }

    public String createSample (Sample sample)
    {
        try
        {
            Sample2Repository repo = new Sample2Repository ();
            Sample2 sample2 = repo.getSample2(sample.getSampleId());
            Sample.setSample2Id(sample2.getId());

            retur sampleDao.save(sample).getId().toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error while creating sample.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

*Sample Document:* I dont think my documents are bigger in size to create problem for MongoDB. There were no other queries being called during load testing. Only CreateSample operation was running.

```
{
    "sample2Id":"593e346cfeaa9e62d1706bb5"
    , "sample3Id" : "593e4159729f5d04db7b6da2"
    , "actualTime":"21/06/2017 09:18:00"
    , "uploadTime":"21/06/2017 09:18:00"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did some copyediting on your question, I hope you like it. I think you need to describe more where your webserver is running in relation to your MongoDB. The "Host CPU" that is at 100% is the MongoDB CPU, is that correct? How is the network connection between your webserver and your MongoDB server? Where are you running your benchmark? You run the test for 24 hours, but can you describe what happens during those 24 hours?

Comment: If the CPU is running at 100%, with the host even refusing network connections, why do you assume to have an IO problem?

Comment: If a simple insert test in JavaScript or Python is significantly faster, have you looked into the differences with your API implementation? For example: is your API inserting much larger documents, maintaining more indexes, or doing more processing? I think you need to share more details of your API implementation and environment. Where are you running the web server, app server, and MongoDB server? How many concurrent connections does your API server use? How large is your data set (in GB)? What monitoring do you have in place during the load test? What other queries does your API generate?

Comment: Your question is far too ambiguous. The problem could be latency between the client and the MongoDB server, it could be that the software you're using can't generate enough load, it could be network throughput, etc. You need to give significantly more detail if you want help.

Comment: @All I will add more details here like AWS architecture, JAVA code, Load Test environment here shortly. I have found some leads to try. I will try those and get back to you. Thanks for support.

Comment: @Law29 I like the wording. Its easier than mine. Thanks.

Comment: @Stennie Please see the updates. I am trying to give as much information as I gather.

Comment: I do not know Mongo, but the singleton stuff does look odd, and there is nothing to show connections are ever flushed / closed. As a starter, I would suggest you look into the connection pooling options available in Tomcat and if they are compatible with the mongo driver (singletons, especially that way, are generally discouraged in application servers due to the was resources are handled). This should at least rule out connection handling.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still too many variables to understand what might be going astray. Your original description mentions 100% CPU and dropped connections with testing on EC2. Your GIF animation appears to be running locally on a MacBook Pro with a steady state of 102 connections (presumably the default of 100 connections for Java driver connection pool plus `mongostat` and `mongo` shell). I would try to simplify your testing/profiling so you can focus on the problem. For example, start by testing locally on your MacBook or `m4.large` before introducing a remote client.

Comment: I would compare resource utilisation with your benchmark tests using other drivers: how are they using connections and resources versus your Java implementation? If your limitation isn't actually CPU or network, you could try adjusting the `maxPoolSize` parameter for the Java driver to allow more connections than the default 100 (see: [MongoClientURI documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/?com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html)).

Comment: Other suggestions to consider: check for any obvious startup warnings in the `mongo` shell; don't use a `t2.micro` (1GiB RAM and limited network) as a client for benchmarking; definitely use SSD for your MongoDB dbPath; monitor resources using a more comprehensive tool than `mongostat` (eg. MongoDB Cloud Manager); use an APM (Application Performance Monitoring) tool to help profile your app execution; separate your app server from your MongoDB server so they aren't competing for resources.

Comment: @Stennie I will definitely try increasing pool size and revert back. Thats seems very obvious and easily implementable solution. I dont have any warming while starting the server. There were some but resolve those very early.